# How to understand the specification of a Wireless AP Router

Tags: specifications

There is one specification of Wireless AP Router, i am not clear with some parts of it.

so anyone can tell me how to learn the specification?

```
Software Specification

Standards IEEE 802.11g, IEEE 802.11b
Wireless Signal Rates With Automatic Fallback 11g: Up to 54Mbps(dynamic)
11b: Up to 11Mbps(dynamic)
Frequency Range 2.4-2.4835GHz
Wireless Transmit Power (MAX) 19dBm (MAX EIRP)
Modulation Technology IEEE 802.11b: DQPSK, DBPSK, DSSS, and CCK
IEEE 802.11g: BPSK, QPSK, 16QAM, 64QAM, OFDM
Receiver Sensitivity 54M: -68dBm@10% PER
11M: -85dBm@8% PER
6M: -88dBm@10% PER
1M: -90dBm@8% PER
256K: -105dBm@8% PER
Wireless Mode AP Router Mode
AP Client Router Mode (WISP Clent)
Bridge mode (point-to-point / point to Multi-point)
Wireless Range Indoors up to 200m, Outdoors up to 830m
Wireless Security SSID Enable/Disable
MAC Address Filter
64/128/152-bit WEP Encryption
WPA/WPA2/WPA-PSK/WPA2-PSK (AES/TKIP) Encryption
```

Comment: Which part(s) don't you understand ?

Comment: "Wireless Range Indoors up to 200m, Outdoors up to 830m" what is the outdoors and Indoors ?

Answer (score 0):

Indoors and outdoors are as they sound.
Indoors mean inside your house and outdoors mean out in the open with almost no obstacles.

The difference in range is because indoors there are walls, furniture etc as obstacles and devices like microwave ovens, bluetooth and mobile phones which contribute a little to the interference.

Due to these things the signals indoors are weaker as compared to the areas where there were none of the above and you had your wireless router in an open field.